# Save JSON data in Firebase

Tags: python, json, firebase, backend

I got the following json data to save it in

```
   {
    "ACCIONA": {
        "ultimo": 126.1,
        "%dif": 5.52,
        "max": 126.5,
        "min": 119.8,
        "volumen": "174305",
        "efectivo": 21710.34,
        "fecha": "07/01/2021",
        "hora": "Cierre"
    },
    "ACERINOX": {
        "ultimo": 9.82,
        "%dif": 2.96,
        "max": 9.84,
        "min": 9.55,
        "volumen": "1132608",
        "efectivo": 10998.42,
        "fecha": "07/01/2021",
        "hora": "Cierre"
    }
}
```

if I import this data manually to firebase it works perfectly. But if I try to save it with python like this

```
 ref = db.reference('/')

empresasJson = json.dumps(empresasDict, ensure_ascii=True)

ref.set(empresasJson)
```

It saves the entire json as one line instead of saving it with childs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to do this.

```py
ref.set(empresasDict)
```

Based on documentation, it seems that you don't need to serialize your data. So the `json.dumps` is unnecessary

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#python